# how do i automatically adjust the height of a tab to fit content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i would like the tab to adjust to the height of the content within it when calender pops up within the tab. here is my code. Thanks!

```
  <script>
  $(function(){
  $( "#accordion-1" ).accordion({collapsible: true,
  heightstyle: "content"});  

  $("#enable").click(function(){
  $("#accordion-1").accordion("option", "disabled", false);
  $("#accordion-1").accordion("option", "active", 2);
  });

  $("#disable").click(function(){
  $("#accordion-1").accordion("option", "disabled", true);
  });
  });

  $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker-1" ).datepicker();
  });
  $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker-2" ).datepicker();
   });

   </script>


   <div id="accordion-1" >
   <h3>Tab 1</h3>
    <div> 
    Departure City: <input id="dep"></input> 
    Arrival City: <input id="arr"></input>
    </div>
    <h3>Tab 2</h3>
    <div id="select_date" >     
    Onward Departure Date: <input id="datepicker-1"></input>
    Return Departure Date: <input id="datepicker-2"></input>
    </div>
    <h3>Tab 3</h3>
    <div>    
    Traveler 1: <input id="name1"></input>
    Traveler 2: <input id="name2"></input>
    </div>
   </div>
```

when the input section within an accordion style tab is clicked, a date picker pops up to select a date. I would like the tab to adjust to the content height to accommodate the date picker. Any ideas on how to get this done? thanks in advance

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you have but if you don't specify a `height` css property, then it will always be the size it needs to fit the content

[heres](http://jsfiddle.net/ontj347n/) a working fiddle. however as the comment says (Adam), if the content is out of flow this will not work.

***Update***

From what you've provided, I can see what the problem is. I think the date picker has a `position:absolute` which means that it doesn't care what div it's inside of, it will display on top without expanding its parent.

What I would suggest is on the focusin and focusout events of those inputs, to manually expand the tab height, but this will force you to give a specific height for the tab.

[heres](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lxys3Ld/) a fiddle for the first option

Another alternative is to create a div that is about the same size as the date picker inside of your tab with a `display:none` and on focus in/out of the input you can show/hide your div. This div would be completely empty (so nothing will show up when you 'show' it) but it will give the impression that your tab is "expanding".

[heres](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lxys3Ld/1/) a fiddle for the second option

also, I suggest using focusin/focusout because I believe the date picker appears/disappears on those events

***update 2***

[Third DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lxys3Ld/2/)

there is a third way to do this as well. I inspected the date picker recently and it has a unique id. Since the date picker only appears on the focusin event of an input, and disappears on focusout, there should theoretically only be 1 date picker at a time (so unique id will be maintained).

What you can do is get the date picker by id and save it to a variable. Then remove the date picker that appeared initially, and append it to the div you have that wraps the 2 date inputs. Finally, you can set its position to static so that it will automatically adjust the height of your div.

```
var datepicker = $('#ui-datepicker-div');
$('#ui-datepicker-div').remove();
$('#select_date').append(datepicker);
$('#ui-datepicker-div').css('position', 'static');
```

Comment: Not if the "content" is out of flow (e.g. `position: absolute`)

Comment: i included my entire code. I don't have a specified height. When the date picker pops up it overrides the boarder of the tab it is contained in

Comment: @D00ble thank you, sorry I was busy last night. I'm looking at this now